# Laravel stopped working locally, all artisan commands and composer commands will not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have been working on a project for about a month. There have been no major issues. We are about to launch.

An error was reported that a route was not working as intended on staging. I tried to replicate it locally by putting the route into my browser ( but obviously with the local domain path ) and it didnt work. this is the order of events:

that route was causing a permanent redirect. Code looked fine but i noticed the intended get did not seem to be hitting so I put a dd('test'); after it and refreshed and saw the test. So it was bypassing its intended route::get, which was not happening before.

I tried figuring this out, clearing cache and the normal things that could cause this. I then killed the server ( locally ) shut down terminal and restarted it, now everytime I try to run anything it responds with http://localhost

```
CO!!@#!@#!@#:directoryproject username$ php artisan cache:clear
"http://localhost"
CO!!@#!@#!@#:directoryproject username$ php artisan config:clear
"http://localhost"
CO!!@#!@#!@#:directoryproject username$ php artisan serve
"http://localhost"
CO!!@#!@#!@#:directoryproject username$
```

i cannot get anything to work. I tried checking out a different branch, nothing. Composer update, install nothing. I keep getting:

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Comment: Spot on, make this something I can mark as correct and I will do so. Thanks so much.

Comment: Posted it as an answer, cheers!

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've left some debug-lines in my code... I recommend overriding Laravel's `dd()` function with one that leverages Php's `debug_backtrace()`, and sends to your error-log the file and line number that the call was made on.  It'll head off a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've likely got a `dd` statement somewhere like `dd(request()->getHost());` or similar. Do a recursive search starting in the app's root directory for the pattern `dd(`. If that doesn't yield anything, start at the very top pulic/index.php and put in `dd(__DIR__);` statements and attempting to access the app. Then move onto the service providers, http kernel, etc. until you can locate the culprit code.